# no linebreak between opening quotation mark and em-dash

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, csquotes, widows-orphans

In dialogues I often need to use the form `\enquote{---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}`. But sometimes, when the quote begins toward the end of a line, I get an ugly rendering like this:

> d sse lectus lorem sit amet et consectetur quia adipit erit et **« —**
>
> Lorem ipum dolor »

This is a minimal example of this behaviour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\RequirePackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur quia adipit     \enquote{---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}
\end{document}
```

As you see, i use an `\,` between the long dash and the following word but the line is breaked in the rending. I get the same behavior with `~`.

So, how can I force the whole chain “« — Lorem” to be in the same line?

Comment: \mbox{\enquote{---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}}

Comment: An excellent MWE, by the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## First solution

Mico's answers are good, but here's one that doesn't require any packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\newcommand{\denquote}[1]{%
   \enquote{\mbox{---\,}\ignorespaces#1}}

\begin{document}

% orig. form of "paragraph"
d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur 
quia adipit \enquote{---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}

% with \denquote
d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur 
quia adipit \denquote{Lorem ipsum dolor}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

i threw in the `\ignorespaces` just in case the input isn't careful, and begins with a typed space.

## Second solution

You can also create the macro `\longdash` you could use anywhere you need dash and not especially in `\enquote` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\RequirePackage[babel=true]{csquotes}

\newcommand\longdash{\mbox{---\,}\ignorespaces{}}
\begin{document}
d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur quia adipit     \enquote{---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}

d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur quia adipit     \enquote{\longdash{}Lorem ipsum dolor}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I modify you’re answer to add a second solution based on your own one. The second solution seems better for me.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you load the `amsmath` package use its `\nobreakdash` macro as follows:

```
\enquote{\nobreakdash---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\nobreakdash" macro
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\RequirePackage[babel=true]{csquotes}
\begin{document}

% orig. form of "paragraph"
d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur 
quia adipit \enquote{---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}

% with \nobreakdash immed. before "---"
d sse lectus lorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet et consectetur 
quia adipit \enquote{\nobreakdash---\,Lorem ipsum dolor}

\end{document}
```

Comment: seems to me that the `babel` approach might also suppress breaks after hyphens where they would be not only unobjectionable but desirable.

Comment: in the screenshot there is an inserted hyphen at the position of `\babelhyphen{nobreak}`, is that intentional?

Comment: @Marijn - Thanks for pointing out this issue -- I hadn't noticed it myself. Let me look into what's going on.

Comment: @Marijn - I rewrote the answer and dropped the `\babelhyphen{break}` method.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks. Based on your comment and the one by @Marijn, I decided to rewrite the answer and drop the `\babelhyphen{break}` method.